# WPF and data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, isenabled

I have a WPF app where i want to control IsEnabled property of several textboxes in code by setting just one bool. So i decide to add databinding for textboxes IsEnabled property.
Here is the source object definition:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <src:QuestionControlsState x:Key="QuestionContorlsState" IsEnabled="True"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Where 'QuestionControlsState' simple class with only one public property 'IsEnabled'
Then i bind some of textboxes:

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxQuestion" 
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, Source={StaticResource QuestionContorlsState}}">
```

At this point it works fine, when i change IsEnabled attribute in Window.Resources section databinding works.
But i want to control it from code, so i get source object:

```
 QuestionControlsState _questionControlsState = (QuestionControlsState)this.FindResource("QuestionContorlsState");
```

And now when i try to set _questionControlsState.IsEnabled, textbox state not change and there is now warnings in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I'm guessing your `QuestionControlsState` class isn't implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx).

Modify it like this:

```
public class QuestionControlsState : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isEnabled = true;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            isEnabled = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsEnabled"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This will trigger a PropertyChanged event whenever you change the `IsEnabled` property, notifying the view it needs to refresh.

Of course, if you're using the MVVM pattern, the correct way of doing this is binding all textboxes to a boolean IsEnabled property ***in the ViewModel*** and not by trying to find the static resource in codebehind... Then, a simple `IsEnabled = false` in the VM will disable all textboxes (without the need of a staticresource)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the MVVM pattern to passing data to tha XAML view and to encapsulate the view logic and to make the view logic testable.

With [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) its very easy to create a observable property which can be bound to the IsEnabled properties of your controls. You only have to change the Property with a Command to true or false to enable or disable the property.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, Blachshma you was right i forgot to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface on my custom class and now it works like it should. Thank you! I think about MVVM pattern and it looks cool but i just started with WPF and want to learn basics.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to change `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource`.

You can find information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx)